# react-redux error cannot call a class as a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have been learning `react-redux` and when I tried to connect my react component with it, I am getting the following error.

```
connect.js:41 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function
at _classCallCheck (connect.js:41)
at Connect (connect.js:125)
at eval (combineReducers.js:37)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at eval (combineReducers.js:34)
at Map.withMutations (immutable.js:1355)
at eval (combineReducers.js:33)
at computeNextEntry (<anonymous>:2:27469)
at recomputeStates (<anonymous>:2:27769)
at <anonymous>:2:31382
```

I am using `react-redux version 4.4.8` and the `react-boilerplate`. The code that I used is

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

 class Something extends React.Component {

 render(){
 return(
       <div>
          <p>It is working</p>
       </div>
      );
    }
  }

 export default connect()(Something);
```

What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated as I am not able to figure out the issue.

**Edit

I removed the reference to reducers form the route and it worked. Maybe something is wrong with the route.

```
 {
  path: '/something',
  name: 'something',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    const importModules = Promise.all([
      import('./Something'),
    //  import('./Something/reducer')
    ]);

    const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

    importModules.then(([component]) => {
      //injectReducer('something', reducer.default);
        renderRoute(component);
    });
    importModules.catch(errorLoading);
  },
```

Comment: Are are you using the component that you export. Need to see more code

Comment: yes, and are there any other `export`s in the file ?

Comment: I am just using it in the App.js through react-router. If I removed the react-redux from the component it works. It's just after adding connect it starts giving me this error.

Comment: And that's the whole content of the component. There is is no extra export statement.

Comment: connect function requires mapStateToProps arg or null instead

Comment: @user3932437 Can you share the code where you combine reducers?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/releases/tag/v3.4.0. You can check the way they are combining the reducers. One more thing is probably important to mention, I upgraded to React 16.

Comment: @ Mihajlo Jovanović  I try adding the null but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The issue was the order of elements in array importModules.then(([component, reducer]) should be the same as import statement of reducer and component due to the Promise. As you we can see in the bellow code. So the issue was related to `react-boilerplate`.

```
{
 path: '/something',
 name: 'something',

 getComponent(nextState, cb) {
   const importModules = Promise.all([

  import('./Something'),
  import('./Something/reducer')

]);

const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

importModules.then(([component, reducers]) => {

  injectReducer('something', reducer.default);
    renderRoute(component);
});

importModules.catch(errorLoading);
},
```